# adding multiple columns include na in dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, transform

I have dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to create a new column which is the sum of other columns by ignoring `NA` if there is any numeric value in a row. But if **all value** (like the second row) in a row are na, the sum column gets `NA`.

Comment: `df$col <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your data frame is called df

```
cbind(df, apply(df, 1, function(x){if (all(is.na(x))) {NA} else {sum(x, na.rm = T)}))
```

Note that if your data frame has other columns, you will need to restrict the `df` call within `apply` to only be the columns you're after.

Answer (score 1):

As this is your first activity here on SO you should have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which describes how a minimal and reproducible examples is made. This is certainly needed in the future, if you have more questions. An image is mostly not accepted as a starting point.

Fortunately your table was a small one. I turned it into a tribble and then used `rowSums` to calculate the numbers you seem to want.

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  6000, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA,
  100, 7000, 1000,
  0, 0, NA
)

df$sum <- rowSums(df, na.rm = T)
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       x     y     z   sum
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  6000    NA    NA  6000
#> 2    NA    NA    NA     0
#> 3   100  7000  1000  8100
#> 4     0     0    NA     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can count the `NA` values in `df`. If in a row there is no non-`NA` value you can assign output as `NA` or calculate row-wise sum otherwise using `rowSums`.

```
ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0, NA, rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1]  6000    NA 10000  8100     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(6000, NA, 10000, 100, 0), y = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 7000, 0), z = c(NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```